# Primefaces datatable sortBy doesn't work after filterBy

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I'm encountering a strange behaviour of filterBy and sortBy in Primefaces, where filterBy itself works fine and also sortBy itself works fine. I'm even able to sort the datatable by one column and filter afterwards. But I'm not able to filter first and sort afterwards.

I think the core problem is, that I'm using an intermediate datastructure in my value-list.
I'll try to give an example. I have a class `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

When having `List<Person>` in my Bean, the sorting and filtering works fine.

Now I have an additional class `Pet`, which belongs to a `Person`.

Therefore, there is a datastructure `Pair<T1, T2>` modelling such a belonging (unfortunately I'm not able to change this design). The implementation of this datastructure looks like the following:

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> {
    private T1 fst;
    private T2 snd;

    public Pair(T1 fst, T2 snd) {...}

    //Setter & Getter
    
    public Pair() {} // Must've created the default constructor,
                     // because otherwise I got an InstantiationException when filtering
}
```

So finally in my Bean, I have a `List<Pair<Person, Pet>>`, which is shown in the datatable.

As told above the filter (e.g. by person.name) works fine. Also sorting (e.g. by name works fine).
The only problem is when first filtering and then sort by one column, where I get a NullPointerException for the single entries in the datatable.

An analysis of what's going on has shown that after filtering and then sorting, the default constructor of `Pair` is called (the only time; Not during single filtering, not during single sorting, in no other scenario), seems leading to an empty pair (since the setters havn't been called neither).

Does anyone know, why the default constructor is called there? Even in the `List<Person>` scenario, the default constructor of Person isn't called when sorting after filtering.

Comment: What version are you using? Tried with the latest version?

Comment: We're using Primefaces 10 (with Ultima as theme, if that's important)